# use azure dns for External vps

Tags: azure, dns, nameservers

I have a German VPS located at Germany. Its Public IP is like 5.179.x.x
I want to use Azure DNS Zone for this server. I want to use *ns1.MyWebSite.com*  as name server for all of my clients.

I have Created DNS Zone in Azure but Confused that Where to put/write my Name Server (ns1.MyWebsite.com) and where to put my Website where Azure going to Resolve or Direct ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have domain name (bought it from a third party)?

If yes, you can follow those steps to map your domain name to Azure DNS zone:

1.Add **record set** via Azure portal, point to your Azure VM:

[image]

2.Add **NS record** to third party domain register, in my test, my domain name buy from `register.com`, so the settings like this:

```
Host: web.jasonye.com  
Record type:     NS record  
Value:    ns1-01.azure-dns.com
```

After a few mins, you can use `nslookup` to **verify** name resoution is working or not:

```
nslookup -type=SOA jasonye.com
```

3.The following is an example response from the preceding command:

```
C:\Users>nslookup -type=SOA jasonye.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2404:f801:10:12e:fe::2

Non-authoritative answer:
jasonye.com
        primary name server = ns1-01.azure-dns.com
        responsible mail addr = azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 300 (5 mins)
        expire  = 2419200 (28 days)
        default TTL = 300 (5 mins)

ns1-01.azure-dns.com    internet address = 40.90.4.1
```

Then you can use IE or other browser to access it:

[image]

More information about Azure DNS, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns).

> Each registrar has their own DNS management tools to change the name
> server records for a domain. In the registrar's DNS management page,
> edit the NS records and replace the NS records with the ones Azure DNS
> created.

Comment: when i use the command nslookup -type=SOA **linktech.in** ,  it is not showing **ns1-01.azure-dns.com    internet address = myIpAddres**